# Fullscreen on mirrored displays with different geometries

Tags: debian, xfce, multi-monitor, fullscreen

I am using XFCE and I have (finally) recently upgraded from Debian buster to bullseye. Since the upgrade I have a strange issue when using dual monitors.

I regularly plug my laptop to a bigger monitor and simply mirror the displays despite their resolutions being different.
Until the upgrade, maximising a window or entering fullscreen mode while watching a video would (correctly IMO) make the window span the largest of the two screens.
Since the upgrade, it will only cover the smallest of the two screens, leaving part of the desktop background visible around it on the bigger screen.

The workaround I have found is to open arandr, deactivate the primary screen (the laptop's) and then reactivate it. This is obviously suboptimal and I'd like to find a way to get XFCE to revert back to systematically privileging the wider of the two screens as soon as I plug it in.

Edit: turns out I do get the right behaviour when I shut the lid which is already more convenient than (de/re)activating the screen.